# Implicit super constructor getdata() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Trying to write a method to read data from cell and convert it to string.
Method :
p

```
ublic class getStringValue {

    public getStringValue(Cell cell) {

    }
    String display ()
    {
        Cell cell = null;
        DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter ();
        String value = df.formatCellValue(cell);
        return value;
    }


}
calling the method in another class

public class acessUser extends getdata  {

    void login(String filepath ,String filename ,String sheetname) throws IOException{

    File file = new File( filepath + "\\"+ filename)    ;
    FileInputStream datafile    = new FileInputStream(file);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook (datafile);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetname);

    int rownum = sh.getLastRowNum()+1;
    int colnum = sh.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

    String [][] data = new String [rownum][colnum];

    for (int i=0 ; i< rownum ; i++)
    {
  Row row = sh.getRow(i);
          for (int  j =0 ; j < colnum ; j ++)
          {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
            getStringValue gt = new getStringValue(cell);
            String value =  gt.display();
            //java.lang.String value = cell.getStringCellValue();   
          data[i][j]=value;
         System.out.println(value);

        //String ui = data[i][j];

    }
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        acessUser n = new acessUser ();
         n.login("A:\\selenium", "selenium.xls", "sheet1");

    }

}
```

error :- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Implicit super constructor getdata() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Answer (score 1):

You define acessUser as a children class of getdata and you don't define a constructor acessUser() for that class. Then, you try to create an instance of that class by executing `new acessUser ();`. Since no constructor was defined, the constructor of the parent class will be called, i.e. getdata(). But it seems that this constructor is undefined.

By the way, the convention is to use an upper case for the first letter of classes' names. Also, your `display()` method doesn't make any sense to me. You assign null to cell then do `String value = df.formatCellValue(cell);`... I'd advised you to take a step back and think further about your solution and how Java works before going further into this code.

Answer (score 0):

yes it was incorrect with constructor so I changed the code to 
public class getStringValue {

public String display (Cell cell)
    {

```
    DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter ();
    String value = df.formatCellValue(cell);
    return value;

}
```

}

and called the Display method. thanks for helping